# How to unroll a std::tuple<...> when calling a constructor

Tags: c++

I've written a class `shrink_pair` which does the same like `pair` but `first` and `second` are `[[no_unique_address]]`.

I want to write a similar constructor like `std::pair`'s `piecewise_construct` constructor. This constructor should call `first` and `second`'s constructors by unpacking the first and second tuple and doing forward()-ing of the tuples elements.

`std::apply` doesn't seem to work for me since I'm not calling a normal callable object but a constructor. How can I do that?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], it will be more clear than a text description of code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what [`std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple)(C++17) is for:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct Foo {
    Foo(int x, float y) {}
};
struct Bar {
    Bar(int x, float y) {}
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Pair {
    template <typename TupleT, typename TupleU>
    Pair(TupleT&& first, TupleU&& second)
        : first(std::make_from_tuple<T>(std::forward<TupleT>(first))),
          second(std::make_from_tuple<U>(std::forward<TupleU>(second))) {}

    T first;
    U second;
};

int main() { Pair<Foo, Bar> p{std::tuple{1, 1.2f}, std::tuple{2, 2.0f}}; }
```

Comment: This is not correct because the constructor should be valid for non-moveable class, and this requires a move (if the OP wants the standard behavior of `std::pair` for its custom class).

Comment: @Holt I do not believe that my code requires moveable `Foo` or `Bar`, why do you think so?

Comment: I forgot about guaranteed copy-elision with C++17 onwards, and since `make_from_tuple` is C++17, your solution is indeed valid for C++17 onwards.

Comment: @Holt Oh, sorry, yea C++17 but OP specified `std::apply` so I assume that is okay for them.

Answer (score 2):

For C++17 onwards, see [@Quimby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71138655/2666289).

For C++11 and C++14, you need to do it the *old* way with `std::index_sequence`:

```cpp
template <class U, class V>
class custom_pair {
    template <std::size_t... UIs, std::size_t... VIs, class... UArgs, class... VArgs>
    custom_pair(
        std::index_sequence<UIs... >, std::tuple<UArgs... > u_args,
        std::index_sequence<VIs... >, std::tuple<VArgs... > v_args) :
        first(std::forward<UArgs>(std::get<UIs>(u_args))... ), 
        second(std::forward<VArgs>(std::get<VIs>(v_args))... ) { }

public:
    U first;
    V second;

public:

    template <class... UArgs, class... VArgs>
    custom_pair(std::piecewise_construct_t,
        std::tuple<UArgs... > u_args,
        std::tuple<VArgs... > v_args) :
        custom_pair(
            std::make_index_sequence<sizeof... (UArgs)>{}, std::move(u_args),
            std::make_index_sequence<sizeof... (VArgs)>{}, std::move(v_args)) { }
};
```

The standard requires the `std::pair` equivalent constructor to work for **non-moveable** type, so you cannot use intermediate function (such as a custom `std::make_tuple`) in C++14, you have to unpack in the initializer-list of your custom pair constructor.

In C++17, you can use intermediate function such as `std::make_tuple` since you get guaranteed copy-elision, as in @Quimby's answer.

---

Full example on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/7PsEjs18r